# How can I get my recent rx6600 not working with amdgpu official proprietary driver on Ubuntu 20.04.4?

Tags: 20.04, graphics, amd-graphics, amdgpu, amdgpu-pro

The latest rx6600 product is not being properly supported on Ubuntu... I was curious about it. I am currently using AMD RADEON rx6600 mech2x 7nm GPU from MSI. It is on AMD RDNA 2 ARCHITECTURE. My product specs here: [https://www.amazon.com/MSI-Radeon-RX-6600-MECH/dp/B09HXLMG2L/ref=sr_1_1?crid=3CTH9TY3Z7K2F&keywords=MSI+Gaming+AMD+Radeon+RX+6600&qid=1648927900&sprefix=msi+gaming+amd+radeon+rx+6600%2Caps%2C230&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09HXLMG2L)

The firmware rx6600 rdna 2 is using is `dimgrey_cavefish_mec2.bin`

Because it is the 'code name' for the GPU. On Windows, it's being supported now. I mean it's working on windows but not on ubuntu.
My kernel version is:

```
#uname -r 5.13.0-39-generic #44~20.04.4-Ubuntu SMP.
```

I even tried re-compile the entire kernel with option that loads the `dimgrey_cavefish_mec2.bin` firmware file by default.

**To the point of the problem**

On Ubuntu 20.04, drivers are working and installed successfully and amdgpu driver is loaded. amdgpu driver is running but I don't think firmware (`dimgrey_cavefish_mec2.bin`) is recognized after that. But I noticed that it is working properly on Windows. When I type `lshw -c display` it displays just the chip name and is not displaying the name of GPU, however, the rx580 displays its name correctly. When I run opencl calculation applications, it does not work because it is not recognizing the 7nm new rx6600 GPU. That's the real situation going on now and this is the problem?

On Ubuntu 20.10, the firmware is even recognized and when I type `lshw -c display`, it displays the name of GPU but it doesn't run any opencl calculation application even if all the drivers are being installed? this is all the problem. But on Windows, it all runs smoothly.

What is the right solution and do you think this GPU is supported on Ubuntu 20.04 now? Any ideas?

**My approach to this problem:**

First, opencl specific application was not working, it was not recognizing the GPU but it was recognizing the opencl driver. I got mistaken for that the firmware and driver were not working properly.
If I suppose that, if firmware was not recognized, even the Ubuntu desktop even would not work as community expert said to me. So this assumption was wrong.

To the point to be clear, the reason that specific application didn't recognize new rx6600 7nm GPU was that it could not read the available GPU out of the groups of video and render.

Comment: On ubuntu 20.10, the firmware is even recognized and it displays the name of GPU but it doesn't run any opencl calculation application even if all the drivers are being installed? this is all the problem. But on the windows, it all runs smoothly.

Comment: alright, wait a sec...

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by running the following commands.

```
sudo usermod -a -G video $LOGNAME
sudo usermod -a -G render $LOGNAME
```

Below is just checking steps to find out whether your GPU is working properly or not before ahead executing the solution.

```
$ /opt/amdgpu-pro/bin/clinfo
Number of platforms:            1 
   Platform Profile:       FULL_PROFILE
   Platform Version:       OpenCL 2.1 AMD-APP (3188.4)
   Platform Name:          AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing 
   Platform Vendor:        Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
   Platform Extensions:    cl_khr_icd cl_amd_event_callback cl_amd_offline_devices
   Platform Name:          AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
Number of devices: 0
```

```
$ lshw -c display 
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
 *-display
      description: VGA compatible controller
      product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
      vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
      physical id: 0
      bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
      version: c7
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom 
      configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
      resources: irq:62 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f01fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fca00000-fcafffff memory:c0000-dffff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

Comment: amdgpu-install --opencl=rocr,legacy. Since some application only supports rocr implementation of opencl. In general, If you are taking easy, give both of options: rocr, legacy. Done. You can download amdgpu-install from official amd rx6600 product web: https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-6000-series/amd-radeon-6600-series/amd-radeon-rx-6600