# Only one monitor detected by Ubuntu 22.04, many similar questions but solutions to those didn't work for me

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, 22.04, monitor, amdgpu

**Update**

- By trying different things and installing more AMD packages I have managed to get to the "Uh oh...something went wrong" screen before the user list is presented.
- But when I used my USB stick with Try Ubuntu 22.04 I found that I could see **both** monitors and drag screens between them. So somehow the USB ISO is smarter than the installed one (I did install from that exact USB). I just edited the question in case this detail helps (?).
- By using the advance recovery boot mode I was just able to get past the "Uh oh" screen by removing recently added packages, but now I'm back to where only one monitor works.

**Hardware/Software:**

```
        sudo lshw -c video
        [sudo] password for user:
          *-display UNCLAIMED
               description: VGA compatible controller
               product: Navi 23 [Radeon RX 6600/6600 XT/6600M]
               vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
               physical id: 0
               bus info: pci@0000:12:00.0
               version: c7
               width: 64 bits
               clock: 33MHz
               capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
               configuration: latency=0
               resources: iomemory:7c0-7bf iomemory:7e0-7df memory:7c00000000-7dffffffff memory:7e00000000-7e0fffffff ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fcc00000-fccfffff memory:fcd00000-fcd1ffff
          *-graphics
               product: EFI VGA
               physical id: 1
               logical name: /dev/fb0
               capabilities: fb
               configuration: depth=32 resolution=1920,1080

        user@xxxxxx:/mnt/6TBNumber1A/archive4$ sudo xrandr --verbose --listmonitors  
        xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
        Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
        default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (0x523) normal (normal) 0mm x 0mm
            Identifier: 0x522
            Timestamp:  152469548
            Subpixel:   unknown
            Clones:    
            CRTC:       0
            CRTCs:      0
            Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                        0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                        0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
                       filter: 
            _MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
            non-desktop: 0 
                supported: 0, 1
          1920x1080 (0x523) 159.667MHz *current
                h: width  1920 start    0 end    0 total 1920 skew    0 clock  83.16KHz
                v: height 1080 start    0 end    0 total 1080           clock  77.00Hz
        
        uname -a    
        Linux xxxxx 5.15.0-46-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 4 18:03:25 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Machine:
    MSI Aegis ZS 5DQ-274US
    AMD Ryzen™ 7 5700G 8C/16T 3.8-4.6 Ghz 16MB Cache
    Chipset B550
    MSI MicroATX Motherboard
    AMD Radeon™ RX 6600 8GB GDDR6 128-bit
Graphics Card Outputs:
    1 HDMI and 3 DP
My monitors support HDMI only, I use a dongle for DP => HDMI
```

**My Efforts**

I am a long time Ubuntu user but never had a problem with monitor detection before. I do believe I am out of my depth on this. I have tried installing the .deb file from [here](https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-6000-series/amd-radeon-6600-series/amd-radeon-rx-6600) based on [this previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1400748/how-can-i-get-my-recent-rx6600-not-working-with-amdgpu-official-proprietary-driv) along with the 2 usermod commands cited.

I have tried using Ctrl-Alt-F1 and Ctrl-Alt-F7, plus xrandr --auto and systemctl restart gdm from [this previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/707422/how-to-force-ubuntu-to-detect-external-display).

```
user@xxxxxx:/mnt/6TBNumber1A/archive4$ sudo xrandr --auto
[sudo] password for user: 
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
```

The 6600 came with the retail PC I bought, I am willing to replace it with a more Ubuntu friendly one that can support at least 2 HDMI monitors. Please feel free to suggest a cheaper/simpler graphics card I could use and maybe sell the 6600. I am not a gamer.

This is my first askubuntu question, I tried to do as good a job as I could in providing detail.

Answer (score 0):

### Answering My Own Question

OK folks, I finally got the personal time to re-install 22.04 LTS on my server (and all the attendant redoing of samba, fstab, apache2, mysql, etc.)

This time though, I purposely did NOT install the proprietary Radeon graphics drivers, and that resulted in me having both monitors available not only during the "Try Ubuntu" but also after I had installed.

Also, this time I tried to make changes in groups, restarting after each set of changes. I started with fstab for the many UUID to /mnt mappings on this server.

It turns out I had a mistake in fstab which (apparently) resulted in network errors (unable to resolve DNS). Of course I only realized the connection once I eliminated any problem with my network setup, and stumbled on a [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/220377/why-doesnt-network-manager-start-at-boot) via Googling that the network won't come up if the local file system has a problem.

I fixed fstab, rebooted and I had both monitors working, and there was much rejoicing! Also, I have been through additional reboots since then and I still have 2 working monitors.

Sorry, I did not intend to give insufficient information for folks to help me resolve the problem. I had not noticed the network errors, nor did I know my fstab was bad.